# Unable to pass login auth token as param

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, react-navigation

I stored a login auth token in a state and passing it to another screen on navigation as a parameter. But the screen that receives that token as param, shows 'undefined' on console.log(). I don't want to get the token from async storage every time on each screen, instead want to use param passing approach.

Main component that is receiving token as props from parent class and further sending it with navigation to another child screen.

```
class DropdownSales extends Component {
constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.auth,
            TotalSales: [],
            data_default:{},
        }

    }

componentDidMount(){   
        this.fetch_default();
    }

setPickerValue = (newValue) => 
    {

        this.props.navigation.navigate('OemLevelTwo', {value: newValue}, {auth_token: this.state.id});
        this.setState({
          pickerSelection: newValue,
        });


        this.togglePicker();
        ...........
        ...........

    }
}
```

This is the component that needs to use token param.

```
export default class OemLevelTwo extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: '',
            param_oem: '',
       }
   }


async componentDidMount(){
        const param_oem = this.props.navigation.getParam('value');
        const auth_id = this.props.navigation.getParam('auth_token');


        await this.setState({
            param_oem,
            id: auth_id
        });
        console.log(this.state.id, 'in oem level two')
        this.fetch_oem();
    }


fetch_oem = () => {
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
            'x-access-token': this.state.id
        }
      .............
      .............
   }
}
```

When I console from 'OemLevelTwo' it prints `undefined` as output.
Please help to resolve.

Comment: Can you try using this.props.navigation.state.params.'paramName' ?

Comment: Can you point where exactly I should try this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of `.navigate()` can be used to pass params. In your case your are passing  `{value: newValue}` as second parameter and `{auth_token: this.state.id}` as  third one.

So change your line to:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('OemLevelTwo', {value: newValue, auth_token: this.state.id});
```

Now you should be able to use `getParam('auth_token');`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Silly of me to make this error.